# Confusing strcpy() behaviour, concatenating to other strings

Tags: c, strcpy

So Im loading comma seperated text from a file.

```
9780136019701,An Introduction to Organic Chemistry,Timberlake Karen,10,3.54,12-2008
9781506304212,Mathematics for Social Scientists,Kropko Jonathan,7,4.73,12-2015
9781506304213,Discrete Mathematics,Jonathan,15,19.73,10-2013
9780136019702,Chemotherapy,Karen,1,2.54,1-2002
```

Each line will have six properties and I'm using `strtok` to split the line. However very confusing behvaiour is happening and that is I read in the ISBN as the first token, copy it into my `book.isbn` property and then read the next token and copy it into my `book.title`.

When I print out `book.isbn` before and after the title token, i notice that the title was added to both `book.isbn` and `book.title` . Why is that so? I never mentioned `book.isbn` anymore. Whats still pointing at it

```
while (fgets(line, STRING_LENGTH, file) != NULL)
  {
    Book book;

    // Grabbing ISBN
    char *bookToken = strtok(line, ",");
    strcpy(book.isbn, bookToken);

    printf("%s\n", book.isbn);
    // Grabbing Title
    bookToken = strtok(NULL, ",");
    strcpy(book.title, bookToken);

    printf("%s\n", book.isbn);
    
    // Grabbing Author
    bookToken = strtok(NULL, ",");
    strcpy(book.author, bookToken);
```

The output

```
9780136019701
9780136019701An Introduction to Organic Chemistry
9781506304212
9781506304212Mathematics for Social Scientists
9781506304213
9781506304213Discrete Mathematics
9780136019702
9780136019702Chemotherapy
```

Why is it concatenating my title to my `book.isbn` ?? Also my `book.isbn` is `char isbn[13]` so how is it allocating this memory.

I should also say that all my other properties are stored correctly and non of this happens with anything else

Comment: no, check the answer i posted. The print statements are fine as i was checking the values for `book.isbn` before and after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Literally after posting i realized my mistake. I was not giving it enough space by only using `isbn[13]`, i now realize it should be `isbn[14]`